# Is URI https://redis.io/topics/quickstart outdated and abandoned?

Tags: redis

I found this URI https://redis.io/topics/quickstart by google. But where is this URI linked from in official web? I don't find it anywhere in https://redis.io/ and https://github.com/antirez/redis. The reason why I am asking this is because I don't know if this is a dead (outdated) link or whether I should read it or not. Is this URI abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

https://redis.io/community here you find `Fork the **official repository**.` There is the link to github.

https://redis.io/documentation here you find github, too: `Note: The Redis Documentation is also available in raw (computer friendly) format in the redis-doc **github repository**.`

I think the quickstart is something old from redis `Redis version 2.2.12`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. If the link is old, I think it should be removed from the site.